# "depends on who you ask" vs "depends on whom you ask"

Tags: pronouns, case, who-whom

> Use the adjective *exalted* to describe something (or someone) that is raised in rank, value, or power.
>
> > *Which group has the most exalted status at your high school depends on **who** you ask*.

Is the sentence correct or should we use *whom* instead of *who*?

Answer (score 7):

The easy way to tell if you need *who* or *whom* is to substitute it for *he* or *him* and see which one makes sense.

For example:

1. Take the section with who(m) in.

   > Which group has the most exalted status at your high school **depends on who** you ask.
2. Substitute *he* in. Does it make sense?

   > …depends on **he**…
3. Substitute *him* in. Does it make sense now?

   > …depends on **him**…
   >   Yes, it does make sense!
4. Insert into your sentence *who* if *he* worked or *whom* if *him*. Remember the 'm's on whom and him to help you.

So, your final sentence should be:

> Which group has the most exalted status at your high school depends on **whom** you ask.

*Warning*: Many native English speakers find *who versus whom* difficult and frequently get it wrong. This is also due to the fact that it is falling out of fashion and is often seen as archaic.

Comment: Since *who* and *whom* don't pattern like *he* and *him*, this advice is incorrect.

Comment: @snailplane Erm… Look at the Internet. E.g. [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/who-vs-whom-its-not-as-complicated-as-you-might-think/), [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhom.asp)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that many people are wrong :-( [Here is a description written by an actual linguist, Arnold Zwicky.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/004084.html)  As he writes: "This is just a fact of life.  Though they are to some degree parallel, WHO and the ordinary personal pronouns differ in the way Form1 and Form2 are distributed."